# how can I convert angular 2 app.module into es6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

//purposefully removed some imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AddonsModule,
    PageBodyModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    OwlModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: ''
    }),
    NouisliderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I convert this code written Angular 2 in TypeScript into ES6? I only want to convert this @NgModule ({...}) "app.module.ts" part into ES6. Since I have an Angular 2 project which I need to convert into ES6. Up to now I only came up with this issue.

Comment: What is version of Angular?

Comment: Angular 2 or above any version  to es6 @SergeyAndreev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` change the `module` value from whatever it is at the moment to `es6`. When TypeScript transpiles the TS file it will do it in ES6.

If you need to drop TypeScript support and rely on pure JavaScript, you can use the transpiled code for your further work.

#### Update

If you want to generate ES6 code, it is `target` that you need to set, not the `module`. `module` deals with the loader. An example of transpiled code that you can reuse and update would be something like this:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRouteModule } from './app.router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Tab1Component } from './tab1/tab1.component';
import { Tab2Component } from './tab2/tab2.component';
let AppModule = class AppModule {
};
AppModule = __decorate([
    NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            Tab1Component,
            Tab2Component
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRouteModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
], AppModule);
export { AppModule };
//# sourceMappingURL=app.module.js.map
```

in `tsconfig.json` set `target: "es2015"`, you can also set `module` to the same value.

Comment: yes, but I want to know how to hard code @NgModule (app.component.ts) into es6. since I want to make it a separate project rather from angular 2. even I have a separate gulp file.

Comment: The transpiled code will give you the code that you can reuse in order to hard code, wherever you plan to hard code it. Open the JS file and examine it. It will define a `__decorate` variable that you use later to define `declarations`, `exports`, etc.

Comment: BTW the problem is I'm not going to use tsconfig.json I have a separate gulp file which it will convert es6 to es5 using babel and browserify. including watch tasks. :/